# fetching SQL product name using version from microsoft website - powershell / Invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I working on scrapping microsoft website where i want to fetch sql product name such as "SQL Version 2012" using their version "11.0.6607.3".

Basically I want to search for their product name using their Version. Help me with powershell using invoke-webrequest.

Thanks in Advance

This is what I have tried

```
$url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/download-and-install-latest-updates"
$html.content = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri $url

# Find the table rows (tr) in the HTML
$rows = ($html.content).ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('tr')

# Define the version number to search for
$searchVersion = '11.0.5058.0'

# Loop through the rows and find the matching version number
foreach ($row in $rows) {
    $cells = $row.getElementsByTagName('td')
    if ($cells.Count -gt 1 -and $cells[1].innerText -match $searchVersion) {
        # The version number is found in the second cell of the row
        # Output the SQL Server version from the first cell of the same row
        Write-Output $cells[0].innerText
        break  # Exit the loop after the first match is found
    }
}
```

Comment: This site works best when you post code you've already written and describe what isn't working - e.g. an error or unexpected results. Open ended questions like "help me write this functionality" tend to get downvoted and closed - have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how you can improve your question and make it more likely to get a helpful response...

Comment: What website are you scrapping?

Comment: @jdweng. "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/download-and-install-latest-updates" this is website what i am trying

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it (with no error handling) that works with that url *today*, but it's brittle and might break if the page layout changes...

```
$url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/download-and-install-latest-updates";

$html = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing).Content;

$searchVersion = "11.0.5058.0";

# find the version text
$index = $html.IndexOf($searchVersion);

# find the start of the containing "<tr>"
$tr = $html.LastIndexOf("<tr>", $index);

# find the text inside the following "<strong>...</strong>"
$start = $html.IndexOf("<strong>", $tr) + "<strong>".Length;
$end = $html.IndexOf("</strong>", $tr);
$name = $html.Substring($start, $end - $start);

$name
# SQL Server 2012
```

It would probably be better to use a proper HTML parser library like the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), but for a simple use case like this it's probably enough to just do it with basic string searches.

Note that the `ParsedHtml` property isn't available in PowerShell "Core" so if you're writing new code it's more future-proof if you avoid using it and add the `-UseBasicParsing` switch, even if you're targeting Windows PowerShell at the moment.

And since SQL Server doesn't really get new versions *that* frequently, it even might be better to simply have a hashtable hardcoded in your script to do the lookups with...

Comment: Thanks . but its giving me wrong information. basically it is giving previous version of what is suppose to give.

Comment: I get "SQL Server 2012" for ""11.0.5058.0" - what do you get?

Comment: try for this "14.0.3456.2"

Comment: Ok, updated to look for the start of the containing "<tr>" instead of the "<td>" since you're looking for version numbers in any of the "Latest service pack", "Latest GDR" or "Latest cumulative update" columns to identify the row.

Comment: hi @mclayton , Tried your code, for some versions I am getting correct Table name. but for some like - "15.0.4188.2" or "15.0.2000.5" getting error. Let me know if any solution is there. Thanks